# Is possible to excite semiconductor with attosecond laser pulse

Tags: laser, semiconductor-physics

Is possible to excite semiconductor with attosecond laser pulse for generation THz wave?

Comment: Many things are possible, some are actually achievable. This is a very generic question. There is no doubt that a fast pulsed laser, attosecond or not, can excite a semiconductor. Whether the structure will generate THz waves or not is device dependent.

Comment: excite for generate THz wave my friend

Comment: for example excite GaAs with atosecond laser pulse for generation THz pulse Is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ultrashort pulses impinging a semiconductor usually generate some level of THz radiation. Electron-hole pairs in a free standing semiconductor can be generated by resonant absorption or by two-photon absorption, depending on the wavelength. They create a transient radiating dipole through the photo-Dember effect.

If lacking central symmetry, the semiconductor can convert part of the pulse energy into the "zeroth harmonic" through optical rectification.

If put into electric field, the transient introduction (and possibly also disappearance) of photoconductive current can also radiate a strong THz pulse.

The answer is **yes**, but you do not need an attosecond pulse; a 100 fs pulse from quite an ordinary mode-locked oscillator is known to work as needed. The duration of THz pulses is usually an order of magnitude longer than the optical pulses used.